# How to distribute tzedakah percentage wise?

Tags: tzedakah-charity, chesed-kindness

Are there any detailed recommendations from chachamim how to distribute tzedakah percentage wise (how many percent to pikuach nefesh, Torah insitutions/talmidim, how many to poor people, etc.)?  I'm asking how to *divide up* the 10% (or up to 20%), not about how much to give total.

There is a lot of information about priorities but I couldn't find exact percentages.

Comment: [related (not the same)](/a/354/170)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no exact proportions in *tzedaka* and you can/should follow your heart. But there are certain guidelines indeed.

R Hershel Schachter brings the following (from an interview in Jewish Action [here](https://jewishaction.com/religion/jewish-law/charity_in_a_changed_economy_an_interview_with_rabbi_hershel_schachter/))

> The question is what does “precedence” mean? Does it mean you give
>   everything to the poor people in your family? The commentaries assume
>   that this is not the case. **The Chatam Sofer (II: 233-234) writes that
>   you give half of your tzedakah money to family and divide the other
>   half among other poor people.**

He mentions other poskim adjust the split of the tzedaka budget going to those with precedence: **Aruch Hashulchan: 51%, Chochmat Adam and R Moshe Feinstein 67%, Pitchei Tshuva 75%.**

> Here is an example following [the 67% opinion]: Assuming I have $1,000
>   to give to tzedakah, if I have a relative who needs $667, I give it to
>   him. The maximum is $667; but if he needs less, I give him less. Once
>   my relatives are taken care of within the amount of $667, I give up to
>   two-thirds of the remaining money to needy neighbors. And of the
>   remaining money, I similarly give up to two-thirds to aniyei ircha.
>   And so on, through the list of priorities.

For more sources and details on priorities, see [here](http://dinonline.org/2010/08/12/laws-of-tzedakah-part-ii-who-to-give-first/).