# Clarifying exactly the halacha of Maaser

Tags: tzedakah-charity, contemporary-halacha, maaser-tithes

In the past several months I've been deducting 10% of my income and setting it aside. I'm starting to feel confused about whether I'm doing it correctly. I have some accumulated money ready to give to tzedakah but I'm not sure how much to give each organization and I've researched the hierarchy system that suggests I should prioritize giving to family relatives over strangers but it is still highly confusing. Am I supposed to give all my 10% to only poor people each time? How much is it up to my own choice vs what the hierarchy recommends?

I just want to do the right thing and it is unclear how much is up to my preferences.

Edited to make it more general

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya SJN and thanks for this first queston. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Beautiful that you are asking. See related answers below which should help you. Note you do not need to give maaser on repayments of borrowed money (ask your Rav to confirm for you). In a nutshell you have a lot of flexibility how to allocate your tzedaka according to your priorities, once your family has enough food/clothing/lodging for their immediate needs

Comment: related: [What constitutes tzedakah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109024/what-constitutes-tzedakah/109043#109043)

Comment: related: [How to distribute tzedakah percentage wise?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/102105/11501)

Comment: +1 Recommend you consult a Rabbi for personal guidance, and edit the question to make it more general! Regarding types of causes, there is indeed debate whether donations to "chesed" - eg buying sefarim for the public who aren't poor - counts for maaser.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.249.1?lang=he&with=Siftei%20Kohen

Comment: As far as I understand, the *minhag* of *maaser kesafim* was enacted specifically to support local *chinuch* institutions. However, as you point out there is a *halachah* that poor relatives take precedence if you have spare *tzedakah* money, due to the *passuk* of *u'me'besarchah al tisalem* (which is *midivrei neviim* and so more *chamur* than a *minhag*).